EF Core Fluent API One-To-Many Mapping using mapping table [child table]
I'm trying to create a one-to-many mapping using EF Core Fluent API.
I have these 3 tables:

User
Role
User Role Mapping Table


These C# classes represent these tables:
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public class UserRoleMapping
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
}

Using IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : class Fluent api configuration is done for User & Role tables, but I'm not able to make a Fluent API configuration for UserRoleMapping table.
When I tried to run:
var role = await uow.RoleRepository
                    .GetAsync(_ => _.Active,
                              _ => _.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedDate), 
                              s => s.UserRole.User);

My expectation is that I should be able to use that query, when roles are fetched need to fetch associated users information also, which I'm not able to perform.

Below is the configuration
internal class UserConfig : BaseEntityConfig<UserEntity>
{
    private readonly string TableName = DatabaseTableName.User;

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserEntity> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable(TableName);
        builder.HasKey(_ => _.Id);
 
        builder.Property(_ => _.Email).HasColumnName("email_address");

        builder
            .HasOne(_ => _.UserRole)
            .WithOne(_=>_.User)
            .HasForeignKey<UserRoleEntity>(_ => _.UserId);

        //builder.HasOne(_ => _.UserRole)
        //    .WithOne(_ => _.User)
        //    .HasForeignKey<UserRoleEntity>(_ => _.RoleId);

        //builder.Property(_ => _.UserRole).HasColumnName("UserRole");



        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}

Role Configuration
internal class RoleConfig : BaseEntityConfig<RoleEntity>
{
    private readonly string TableName = DatabaseTableName.Role;

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RoleEntity> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable(TableName);
        builder.HasKey(_ => _.Id);
        builder.Property(_ => _.RoleName).HasColumnName("name");
        builder.HasOne(_ => _.UserRole)
            .WithOne(_ => _.Role)
            .HasForeignKey<UserRoleEntity>(_ => _.RoleId);
       base.Configure(builder);
    }
}


Can you please show us those Fluent API configurations for User and Role ?

Updated question

What happens in GetAsync? When asking questions, make sure that there's no black-box code.

That is a many-to-many relationship, not a one to many. Typically you would do away with the "Id" on the UserRole table and use a composite PK based on UserId + RoleId as you wouldn't want duplicate rows doubling up associations between users and roles. Your configuration was trying to set up one-to-one relationships. (HasOne().WithOne()) A one-to-many would see a User having a RoleId where one "role" is associated to many "users". That's not likely the relationship you are looking for vs. a many-to-many. These users belong to these roles. So a user can have many roles, and a role can have many users.
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; } = [];
}

public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; } = [];
}

Then when configuring:
// User EntityTypeConfig
builder
     .HasMany(_ => _.Roles)
     .WithMany(_=>_.Users)
     .UsingEntity("UserRole",
          l => l.HasOne(typeof(Role))
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey("RoleId")
               .HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Role.Id)),
          r => r.HasOne(typeof(User))
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey("UserId")
               .HasPrincipalKey(nameof(User.Id)),
        j => j.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId"));

This configures it without a UserRole entity, though it can alternatively be set up with a defined entity class or via a Dictionary. There are a few options outlined in the docs. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many)
If you do want a relationship through UserRole, such as if there are properties you want added to UserRole for each instance of a relation between a user and a role, then it can be set up explicitly in the relationship but works more as a many-to-one-to-many to mimic a many-to-many:
 public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; } = [];
}

public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; } = [];
}

// User EntityTypeConfig

builder
     .HasMany(_ => _.UserRoles)
     .WithOne(_=> _.User)
     .HasForeignKey(_ => _.UserId);

// Role EntityTypeConfig

builder
     .HasMany(_ => _.UserRoles)
     .WithOne(_=> _.Role)
     .HasForeignKey(_ => _.RoleId);

// UserRole EntityTypeConfig

builder.HasKey(_ => new { _.UserId, _.RoleId } ); // or _.Id if you want a  dedicated Id column.

The drawback of using the explicit entity is that to go from Role to Users or User to Roles it is less convenient. You need to go through UserRoles. I.e.
role.UserRoles.Select(_ => _.User);

instead of:
role.Users;

Mapping the association entity is generally only needed if you want extra properties, for example if you want to record the DateTime a User was associated with a Role. UserRole would have a CreatedDateTime so we would need to map a UserRole to get access to this property. (vs. the CreatedDateTime on a User when the user was created, or CreatedDateTime on a Role for when the role was created.)
